# How To Deploy C#/WPF Application With SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, deployment

I am trying to deploy an application I have created which uses a SQL Server Database (.edmx file). The database was created uses SQL Server Management Studio. What are the steps I need to take to get this application deployed? It needs to create a blank DB with all of the tables when installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would highly recommend using WIX: http://wix.codeplex.com/
This is how to do SQL database stuff with WIX: http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2005/03/30/396338.aspx .

Some other options worth investigating if you don't like Wix are:

Click Once: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
InstallShield: http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm

I believe Microsoft used Wix for the Office 2010 installer. It seems this is the way microsoft is pushing. Wix is free, opensource and extensible with c#. Installshield would be the runner up to me, its closed source I believe and costs money. It is quite famous and is likely quite feature rich.

Comment: Wow. This is incredibly confusing to me. Are there any in depth tutorials for this?

Comment: Create your database by doing this: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/sql/creating-a-database

Comment: Create your data by executing some sql scripts such as: http://www.rrreese.com/Article/Show/WiX%20SQL

Comment: To export your data to sql see this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85186/mysqldump-equivalent-for-sql-server

Comment: To learn WIX, check out this book: http://www.amazon.com/WiX-Developers-Guide-Windows-Installer/dp/1849513724