# generate SQL Script via commandline

Tags: sql, sql-server, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a MS-SQL database and want to generate the script of this database with all the create table, create sequence and insert commands (as a "backup-Script").

I can do this in my MS SQL Server Management Studio manually, but is there a commandline command for this?
For MySQL Databases I found this:

`$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql`

in addition to my primary question: how do I rewrite the "login" part (`u [uname] -p[pass]`), when I want to use my Windows-Authentification?

Comment: Your MySQL Server is an Enterprise Edition?

Comment: I've ask because it looks like only the Enterprise Edition supports integrated Windows authentication. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-pluggable-authentication.html I didn't find if especially `mysqldump` supports it and how. But in any case the Enterprise Edition seems to be required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqldump equivalent for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85186/mysqldump-equivalent-for-sql-server)